# Variance problem with probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three cards are drawn sequentially from a deck that contains 16 cards numbered 1 to 16 in an arbitrary order. Suppose the first card drawn is a 6.

Define the event of interest, A, as the set of all increasing 3-card sequences, i.e. A={(x1,x2,x3)|x1 < x2 < x3}, where x1,x2,x3∈{1,⋯,16}. Define event B as the set of 3-card sequence that starts with 6, i.e. B={(x1,x2,x3)|x1=6} or simply B={(6,x2,x3)}

Let $S_{x_3=t}$ represent the subset $\{(6,x_2,t)|6 \lt x_2 \lt t\}$, then $|A \cap B|=\displaystyle\sum_{t=8}^{16}∣∣S_{x_3=t}∣∣$.

Then what is |A∩B|=?

Comment: I could not read "Let Sx3=t represent the subset {(6,x2,t)|6 < x2 < t}, then |A∩B|=∑t=816∣∣Sx3=t∣∣" so please check my edit is what you intended

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- $S_{x_3=8} = \{(6,7,8)\}$
- $S_{x_3=9} = \{(6,7,9),(6,8,9)\}$
- $S_{x_3=t} = \{(6,7,t),\ldots,(6,t-1,t)\}$
- Count each
- Add up the counts

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well then $A\cap B=\left\{ \left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right)\mid x_{1}<x_{2}<x_{3}\wedge x_{1}=6\right\} =\left\{ \left(6,x_{2},x_{3}\right)\mid6<x_{2}<x_{3}\right\} $
so $\left|A\cap B\right|=\left({10\atop 2}\right)=45$

Two distinct numbers are to be chosen from $\left\{ 7,\cdots,16\right\} $.

This is an alternative way to find $\left|A\cap B\right|$ and I should prefer it, but off course I don't know the context of your problem.